# Struggling with the high-chart to get the data correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of object as you see bellow : 
As shown, each name has some data for the year 2019 & 2020. I am trying to get the data for both year. for the actual value is should be as a column & target as a line. 
please refer to this https://codepen.io/Zerka1982/pen/LweBLJ
Please see what I've tried in my code:

I've created 1 array in order to store the data this way, for each item :

The problem is is clear on the high-chart, instead of seeing data for different year , I see all data for 2019.

Basically, I need to have for each year own data ( actual and target  ). 
In case you made any correction of own version, please share it with me.

I appreciate your support guys. Thank you!
please refer to this https://codepen.io/Zerka1982/pen/LweBLJ

```
$(function() {
    var seriesAct = [];
    var seriesTar = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(uniqueNames.length != 0) {
    seriesAct.push({
    name:  array[i].name ,
    type: 'column',
    data: [array[i].actual] },
    {name: array[i].name,
    type: 'line',
    data: [array[i].target]
    });
    }
    }
```